# How to get the table cell of a row that was clicked with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, row

I have a table in HTML, and I have an onclick event for its rows.

I was wondering if it was possible to find out which cell of the row was clicked, without having a seperate handler for each cell?

I have a table:

```
<tr class="new_row">
   <td class="date">date</td>
   <td class="name">name</td>
   <td class="delete">delete</td>
</tr>
```

and jquery:

```
$(".new_row").click(function(){
   if(delete was clicked){
       delete the row
   }
});
```

That is what I want to do basically, detect if the delete cell was clicked.

Is this possible?

Comment: Assuming you are going to have more than 1 row, you'll want to use `class='date'` instead of ID

Comment: wow. You guys are good. All 3 of you caught that I had id instead of class!

Comment: Are all delete able rows present at DOM initiation or are you adding rows dynamically which may need to be able to be deleted?

Comment: well, I am sort of cheating, after new rows are added, the page is refreshed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the id of the [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/). If it matches `delete`, then you can process a delete.

However, since this in a table, I'm guessing that you have multiple rows. If this is the case, does that mean that you have multiple cells with the same ID? If so, this isn't valid HTML and it could cause problems with your jQuery code, when you try to use CSS selectors.

Comment: See the `td.delete`? He wants to click that and delete the row.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. I still want the onclick registered to the row, but then I want to check which cell of the row was clicked! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Firstly you should not define more than one element with same id, it will cause trouble, you can replace `id='delete'` with `class='delete'`.

```
// on click td with class delete:
$("td.delete").click(function(){
   //delete was clicked so remove tr
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: errr ya, they are classes, my bad

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vGS22/)**

```
$(".new_row").click(function(event){       
    if($(event.target).text() == 'delete')
    {       
      $(this).remove();      
    }
});
```

Comment: ya, that is exactly how I did it! (except I need to make an ajax call first to remove from the database)